# No entries in phplist tables

Tags: phplist

I downloaded latest version of phpList which is 3.0.5. I copied lists folder in localhost.

Then i tried to open host/lists/admin.
It should have created all the tables by itself, but it didn't.
And i got this error

[image]

So i created all the steps manually from phpList.sql which was inside downloaded folder.

then again when i opened host/lists/admin, this error was gone. But i wasn't able to login into this by using username "admin" and password "phplist" . So i searched how to change password and found we can do it by changing password field in admin table.

But how i can do this ? 
As I don't have single entry in any of the tables, how can change/create password for admin account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I inserted one row in admin table. Then I logged in with same credentials which i entered manually in tables. After successfully login it asked me to update database and i updated it. Now it's working.